# Using namespaces on XML

Tags: php, xml

I need work with namespaces on XML from a code and do something with it. For instance:

```
    <system:include file="./test.php" cache="true" />
```

That would be the final output of the content, but it is necessary to process the special tags (like the `system:include`) before send to client.

So I will get all elements of final output to search about *namespaced* tags or specific ones. The problem is that if I use `DOMDocument` and read like XML, I have some problems with namespaces declaration (`Namespace prefix system on include is not defined in Entity`).

My test code is:

```
<?php

    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $document->loadXML('
        <system:include file="./test.php" cache="true" />
    ');

    foreach($document->childNodes as $node) {
        var_dump($node->nodeName);
    }

?>
```

I need do it because I need process some special tags and converts it to real HTML. For instance: convert `<b>` to `<strong>` (just an example!) or make something better like include and cache a specific page using tags.

Another example:

```
<h7>Hello World!</h7>
```

Converts to:

```
<div class="h7">Hello World!</div>
```

**Note:** the `ob` contents will be sent to a specific method that will search by this special tags. So I don't know if I can make namespaces declaration before (will be hard and slowly, probably).

Bye!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can get it to work if I specify a root element in the XML, and then declare the system namespace inside the root element.  `<root xmlns:system="system">...</root>`

```
<?php

function dump($root) {
    foreach($root->childNodes as $node) {
        echo $node->nodeName;
        echo "\n";
        dump($node);
    }
}

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML('<root xmlns:system="system"><system:include file="./test.php" cache="true" /></root>');

dump($doc);

?>
```

Comment: Good... But if I don't know what is the namespaces? Because I can have `X` namespaces and I don't know the name of each one. Just a help... If it doesn't is possible I think that I know what I can do...

Comment: I'm not sure how to make DOMDocument parse an XML document with unknown namespaces without warning about them.  You could suppress errors with $doc->loadXML('...', LIBXML_NOERROR);